# Android - border for button

Tags: android, button, border, android-button

How do I add a border to a button? Is it possible to do this without resorting to use of images?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626554/android-draw-border-in-imageview/7626628#7626628
Same way as here :)

Answer (score 474, accepted):

Step 1 : Create file named : my_button_bg.xml

Step 2 : Place this file in res/drawables.xml

Step 3 : Insert below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:endColor="#00FF00"
    android:angle="270" />
  <corners android:radius="3dp" />
  <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

Step 4: Use code "android:background="@drawable/my_button_bg" where needed eg below:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your Text"
    android:background="@drawable/my_button_bg"
    />
```

Comment: thanks.+1 for this.After saving it into drawable folder as a xml file.How can we use it ?

Comment: @AndroidPower you can use it with R.drawable.FILE_NAME

Comment: Where does this code go, in the .axml code for the markup for the button? Does it go in a styles.xml type file?

Comment: I used just the stroke (and made it white) to outline a Button with white. Works great with 4.4 but in 4.0.3 the button goes black - any ideas why?

Comment: @Kibi sorry someone edited my answer and gave you incorrect advice.  I have changed it but I'm shocked that someone can edit an accepted answer and change the usefulness.

Comment: can we handle clicked and focus cases whit <selector>

Comment: You should use DP not PX. Never PX in android.

Answer (score 119):

### • `Android Official Solution`

Since **Android Design Support v28** was introduced, it's easy to create a bordered button using [`MaterialButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton). This class supplies updated Material styles for the button in the constructor. Using `app:strokeColor` and `app:strokeWidth` you can create a custom border as following:

## 1. When you use `androidx`:

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
}
```

**• Bordered Button:**

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="MATERIAL BUTTON"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:strokeColor="@color/green"
    app:strokeWidth="2dp" />
```

**• Unfilled Bordered Button:**

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="UNFILLED MATERIAL BUTTON"
    android:textColor="@color/green"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
    app:cornerRadius="8dp"
    app:rippleColor="#33AAAAAA"
    app:strokeColor="@color/green"
    app:strokeWidth="2dp" />
```

---

## 2. When you use `appcompat`:

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

**style.xml**

Ensure your application theme inherits from `Theme.MaterialComponents` instead of `Theme.AppCompat`.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

---

**• Bordered Button:**

```
<android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="MATERIAL BUTTON"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:strokeColor="@color/green"
    app:strokeWidth="2dp" />
```

**• Unfilled Bordered Button:**

```
<android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="UNFILLED MATERIAL BUTTON"
    android:textColor="@color/green"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
    app:cornerRadius="8dp"
    app:rippleColor="#33AAAAAA"
    app:strokeColor="@color/green"
    app:strokeWidth="2dp" />
```

---

## Visual Result

[image]

Comment: I see you've got textColor and textSize declared in your button XML. What do you suggest if someone already has a style defined for textColor and textSize and now they want to add the `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"` ?

Comment: I've got it figured out, see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes#Customize

Comment: As you mentioned, it is possible to define a style which inherits from borderless style, then add preferred attributes according to the base style.

Comment: Slightly OT, but what's the interesting 4th icon in the action bar at the bottom of the GIF? (Also it looks like the GIF was grabbed from a real device, cool)

Comment: @i336_ :) Yes, I was running it on a real device which supports 2 SIMs.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but for me in the • Unfilled Bordered Button, I had to change,     app:backgroundTint="@color/transparent" to app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: @xarly: You are right since I was declared transparent color in the project resource values.

Comment: it doesnt work for me in Xamarin.Android. the Unfilled Bordered Button with the same code does not have solid border but it has something like a shadow border around the button

Comment: worked for me using <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"

Answer (score 49):

Create a `button_border.xml` file in your drawable folder.

**res/drawable/button_border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#FFDA8200" />

    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#FFFF4917" />

</shape>
```

And add button to your XML activity layout and set background `android:background="@drawable/button_border"`.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_border"
    android:text="Button Border" />
```

Answer (score 21):

create drawable/button_green.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
    android:startColor="#003000"
    android:centerColor="#006000"
    android:endColor="#003000"
    android:angle="270" />
  <corners android:radius="5dp" />
  <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#007000" />
</shape>
```

and point it out as `@drawable/button_green`:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_green"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 20):

Please look here about creating a shape drawable
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Once you have done this, in the XML for your button set `android:background="@drawable/your_button_border"`

Answer (score 10):

If your button does not require a transparent background, then you can create an illusion of a border using a Frame Layout. Just adjust the FrameLayout's "padding" attribute to change the thickness of the border.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="1sp"
        android:background="#000000">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Your text goes here"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:padding="10sp"
            />
</FrameLayout>
```

I'm not sure if the shape xml files have dynamically-editable border colors. But I do know that with this solution, you can dynamically change the color of the border by setting the FrameLayout background.

Answer (score 7):

In your XML layout:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancelskill"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/button_border"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

In the drawable folder, create a file for the button's border style:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#f43f10" />
</shape>
```

And in your Activity:

```
    GradientDrawable gd1 = new GradientDrawable();
    gd1.setColor(0xFFF43F10); // Changes this drawbale to use a single color instead of a gradient
    gd1.setCornerRadius(5);
    gd1.setStroke(1, 0xFFF43F10);

    cancelskill.setBackgroundDrawable(gd1);

    cancelskill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cancelskill.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            cancelskill.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#f43f10"));

            GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();

            gd.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF); // Changes this drawbale to use a single color instead of a gradient
            gd.setCornerRadius(5);
            gd.setStroke(1, 0xFFF43F10);
            cancelskill.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);

            finish();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

I know its about a year late, but you can also create a 9 path image
There's a tool that comes with android SDK which helps in creating such image
See this link: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

PS: the image can be infinitely scaled as well

Answer (score 4):

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/addBtn"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                app:cornerRadius="8dp"
                app:strokeColor="@color/blue"
                app:strokeWidth="2dp"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

With the **Material components library** just use a **`MaterialButton`** with the `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton` style.

You can customize  color and width with the **`strokeColor`** and **`strokeWidth`** attributes

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
   ....
   style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
   app:strokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

[image]

---

With **Jetpack compose** use an [**`OutlinedButton`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#OutlinedButton(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.material.ButtonElevation,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke,androidx.compose.material.ButtonColors,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Function1)).
Use the **`border`** attribute to customize width and color.

```
OutlinedButton(
    onClick = { },
    border = BorderStroke(1.dp, Color.Blue),
) {
    Text(text = "BORDER")
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your drawable folder create a drawable file called gradient_btn
and paste the code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient android:startColor="#7BF8C6"
    android:centerColor="#9DECAD"
    android:endColor="#7BF8C6"
    android:angle="270" />
<corners
    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="15dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
    />
<stroke android:width="3px" android:color="#000000" />

</shape>
```

Then in your Button code in xml call the file you created:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_btn"/>
```

Output - Will be a button with gradient and border.

Note - You can change the Hexa decimal codes of the buttons as you wish and also you can change the stroke width.