# Android layout with 4 squares and a button inside each square

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create 4 squares and in each square i want to create a small button. The square must be visible and must have a border.

I know how to create 4 buttons as a square but i don't know how to create a border around each square. But i want to to be size independent, now the buttons are very big...

my example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/magaLoginLayout"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <Button android:text="@+id/Button01" android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="160dip" android:layout_height="160dip" android:layout_marginTop="20dip"></Button>
        <Button android:text="@+id/Button03" android:layout_below="@+id/Button01" android:id="@+id/Button03"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button01" android:layout_height="160dip" android:layout_width="160dip"></Button>
        <Button android:text="@+id/Button04" android:layout_below="@+id/Button01" android:id="@+id/Button04"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button03" android:layout_height="160dip" android:layout_width="160dip"></Button>
        <Button android:text="@+id/Button02" android:id="@+id/Button02" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button01" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Button01" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_height="160dip"></Button>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Check this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690416/android-border-for-button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want to create layout look like this screenshot ?

[image: This is layout for my apps named Call & Sms Blocker.]

Code for this layout :

1. main_screen.xml

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@drawable/bgimage2" >

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:text="Call & SMS Blocker" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" /> 

     <Button 
      android:id="@+id/blocked_sms"
      android:layout_width="162dp" 
      android:layout_height="162dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
      android:background="@drawable/buttoneffects" 
      android:focusable="true" 
      android:textColor="#000000" 
      android:textStyle="bold" /> 

    <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/imagebutton1" 
     style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" 
     android:layout_width="50dp" 
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/blocked_sms" 
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
     android:layout_marginTop="136dp" 
     android:background="@drawable/buttoneffectpower" /> 

     <Button 
        android:id="@+id/blocked_calls"
        android:layout_width="162dp" 
        android:layout_height="162dp" 
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/blocked_sms"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/blocked_sms"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttoneffectssecond" 
        android:focusable="true" android:text="Blocked Calls"
        android:textColor="#000000" 
        android:textStyle="bold" /> 

     <Button 
        android:id="@+id/settings" 
        android:layout_width="162dp" 
        android:layout_height="162dp" 
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/blocked_calls"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imagebutton1" 
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttoneffectfourth" 
        android:focusable="true" android:text="Settings" 
        android:textColor="#000000" android:textStyle="bold" /> 

    <Button 
     android:id="@+id/blacklist" 
     android:layout_width="162dp" 
     android:layout_height="162dp" 
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/settings"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/settings" 
     android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" 
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imagebutton1"
     android:background="@drawable/buttoneffectthird" 
     android:focusable="true" 
     android:text="Blacklist" 
     android:textColor="#000000" 
     android:textStyle="bold" /> 

     <Button 
       android:id="@+id/help" 
       android:layout_width="150dp" 
       android:layout_height="70dp" 
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/blocked_sms"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="69dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttoneffectsimple" 
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:text="Help" 
    android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:textStyle="bold" /> 

      <Button 
     android:id="@+id/block_last_number" 
     android:layout_width="330dp" 
     android:layout_height="70dp" 
     android:layout_above="@+id/help" 
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/help" 
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/settings" 
     android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
     android:background="@drawable/buttoneffectsimple" 
     android:focusable="true" 
     android:text="Block Last Number" 
     android:textColor="#000000" 
     android:textStyle="bold" /> 

      <Button 
    android:id="@+id/aboutus" 
    android:layout_width="150dp" 
    android:layout_height="70dp" 
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/help" 
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/help"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/block_last_number"
    android:background="@drawable/buttoneffectsimple" 
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:text="About Us" 
    android:textColor="#000000" 
    android:textStyle="bold" /> 

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

Code for button effects (xml files layout):

```
    <Selector>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/blockedsms"><shape>
        <solid android:color="#fff" />

        <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#444" />

        <corners android:radius="6dp" />

        <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#10000000"
           android:startColor="#10FFFFFF" />

        <corners android:bottomRightRadius="50dp" />
    </shape></item>

       </selector>
```

Now in other xml button effects layout, you have to change

```
      <corners android:bottomLeftRadius 
      <corners android:topRightRadius
      <corners android:topLeftRadius

      and so on......
```

Hope! This will help.
Cheers !!!

Comment: Not an answer, and you could at least provide some text, instead of just answering a question with another question.

Comment: Sorry for that but I just want to confirm, is requirement matches this screenshot or not ? If yes then I'll provide whole code about this layout.

Comment: @Manish Android yes this would be nice if you can give code example. Thx

Comment: and what about Failed to find style 'textViewStyle' in current theme
Failed to find style 'buttonStyle' in current theme
Failed to find style 'imageButtonStyle' in current theme

Comment: You can delete this line :
           style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" 
As it is used when I drag ImageButton fromlayout panel to my source code. It is style of that image button.

Comment: Should my answer will get best answer award now ? Lolz.

Comment: thank you. it will, i just need to make it work :) is this code for RelativeLayout correct? <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

Comment: @user1545584: can you please tell me what is this line , I mean this blocked sms is a icon or again some drawable ? <item android:drawable="@drawable/blockedsms"><shape>

Answer (score 6):

Since the border part seems to be answered by the comment to your question, here is an answer to the layout part:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

This layout will be independent of the size of the screen and whether it's in landscape or portrait mode. Define your own margins around the buttons ;-)

To use the border from the comment just add:

```
android:background="@drawable/back"
```

to the buttons. back is the name of the shape you created.