# How to align four image buttons in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have four image buttons, how could I fix the alignment like this:

```
button1 (80 * 80)    button2 (80 * 80)
button3 (80 * 80)    button4 (80 * 80)
```

How do I write my xml? Also I want to be able to
load images dynamically into these 4 image buttons.
How do I do that? Could I have arbitrary sized images
or I can only use 80*80 sized images?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you tried anything to make this work?

Comment: Its a better to use **GridView**.

Comment: My answer will help you. Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555106/android-layout-with-4-squares-and-a-button-inside-each-square/12555252#12555252

Comment: I could make it work, but the view is ugly... what I did is:  <RelativeLayout> button1, button2 button3, button4

Comment: So you need 4 buttons 2 above and 2 below right ,didnt you try using weight of 0.5 to each