# Setting a Button with background Image and Round corners

Tags: android, button

I know there are already questions like this but i cannot find the answer for my uestion. Please Help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button"
      android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button" />
</selector>
```

i already set the background but i dont know how to make the edges round.

Comment: You have to apply css.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771367/create-button-with-rounded-corners-in-android. check this link

Answer (score 1):

Create your own custom button like this

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#1a1a1a" />
</shape>
```

Also check this on [Developers Site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)

Comment: how about the background?