# Change background color of button when clicked

Tags: android

At the moment I have a button in my view. What I want is that when it gets clicked that the buttonbackgroundcolor changes to an ARGB of 25,0,0,1 , meaning 25% opacity. It should be that color every time the user touches the button. So when it is not touched the button's background should be 100% transparent.

Here's my .xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MyActivity2"
android:background="#ffdb4b5e">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="72sp"
    android:background="#00000000"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/thing1"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

onClick method:

```
n.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Random RAND = new Random();
            int position = RAND.nextInt(colors.length);
            int position2 = (index++);
            String nextValue = colors[position];
            String textValue = values[position2];
            tv.setText(textValue);
            rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(nextValue));
            n.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(25,0,0,1));
        }
    });
}
```

as you can see I already set the background to 25,0,0,1. The problem is though that when the button gets pressed the color changes permanently to 25,0,0,1...

Comment: i think u need selector

Comment: Was thinking that too, but due too my noobness I'm failing to do that.

Comment: use a selector http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771367/create-button-with-rounded-corners-in-android or onTouch down set one color and action up set the default color. Use onTouchlistener

Comment: Can you post the code you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1** Easy way

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Do your work here
                button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
            }
        }
});
```

**Solution 2**
Add this **implements OnTouchListener** to your class then in onCreate() add the setOnTouchListener to your button **button.setOnTouchListener(this);** and finally add this below override method

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int action = event.getAction();
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            if (v == button) {
                //do your work here
                button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            }

    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        //}
    }
    return true;
}
```

Still if u have doubt check the below **Example**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnTouchListener{
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnTouchListener(this);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
        .commit();
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int action = event.getAction();
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        if (v == button) {
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }

    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: add the override method to your code the error will go off

Comment: Lets comment a few times here then it will automaticaly give a chat lingk

Comment: Chat chat chat chat hehe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59457/discussion-between-s3a2r0a8v9a6n9a-and-cristianowilson).

Answer (score 0):

To have the button change when "pressed" and then change back when the user stops pressing it you need a selector:

[android button selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector)

It handles "focused" and other things too.