# How yo add glowing effect on button with background?

Tags: android

I have taken a button in my xml and set its background img1 now on the click of that button i want white glow around that button edges . I have refereed this links  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html     [Android ImageButton with a selected state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604599/android-imagebutton-with-a-selected-state)      [Standard Android Button with a different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a white border to the button. please enter this question to see how to add border: [Android - border for button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690416/android-border-for-button)

Store the xml in

> res/drawable/filename.xml

And then you can access it like this:

```
In Java: R.drawable.filename
In XML: @[package:]drawable/filename
```

Comment: Hey Omar....
Where to store that xml file and how to access it please reply soon..

Comment: waiting for your reply