# Select a button android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have many buttons with different color names on them.

```
yellow - red - blue
```

I want, when user tap on one it creates a border around it (select the button) and in the end of my activity I have another button to SAVE the color user selected.

```
<Button
        android:text="Yellow"
        android:layout_width="111dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />

<Button
        android:text="Red"
        android:layout_width="111dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />


<Button
        android:text="SAVE"
        android:layout_width="111dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonsave" />
```

java

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.color);

    Button btnYellow;
    btnYellow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button btnRed;
    btnRed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String url2 = intent.getStringExtra("image");




    btnYellow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });


}
```

how can I selected a button when user click on it and get a value (red,green, red1) when user click in save?

Comment: You can Change Background color of Button on Click event

Comment: you need the RadioButtons or CheckBoxes, not regular Buttons

Comment: first I'd like to select one button when user click, eg: red. them, when he clicks on `save` I show a message saying `red`, for example. @Chetan

Comment: take one variable to hold colorcode which has value assigned from button clicks and when you click on save button you have selected colorcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place each button in a `FrameLayout`. This will give the button a border. Changing the background color on the `FrameLayout` will change the border of the button.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnYellow"
        android:layout_width="111dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Yellow" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Set an `onClickListener` for the buttons that looks something like the following, but don't use the hard-coded colors - this is just an example. `mLastClicked` is a member variable defined as `Button mLastClicked`.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (mLastClicked !=null) {
        ((FrameLayout) mLastClicked.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    }
    mLastClicked = (Button) view;
    switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnYellow:
            ((FrameLayout) view.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFF00);
            break;

        case R.id.btnRed:
            // Similar to yellow
            break;

        case R.id.btnSave:
            // Do something with mLastClicked to save it
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your button as a shape To give it a border, use the  element (name the file your.xml and place it in res/drawables):

and Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690416/android-border-for-button)