# How can I make a dashed shaped Tab selection using buttons in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

[image]

I am using the button as the side tab menus for item like 'Home','Games',etc. I can't figure out how to get such rectangle shape selection when button is pressed.
Can I use drawable res for the same. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a custom drawable with left margin rectangle drawable 1dp to 5dp width. I think you already have the logic for toggling the current tab's button to only have this drawable.

Comment: Yes, I have the logic for drawable selection on the toggle. Can you please elaborate a little like what should I use selector, shape or should create a layout for the same in drwable?

Comment: You can refer the answer here for code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690416/android-border-for-button